# Utilising Parcelable to send Array across two activities

Tags: java, android, parcelable

I'm trying to send a populated array of a created class called *'Exercise'* between two activities, and I've read the best way to do so I utilising the Parcelable class.

Activity 2 crashes whenever it starts. I've followed tutorials online for this and this is how they treat the sending of the data.

Exercise Class:

```
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

public class Exercise implements Parcelable {

    public String Name = "";
    public int Time = 0;
    public boolean SwitchDirection = false;

    Exercise(String n, int l, boolean s){
        Name = n;
        Time = l;
        SwitchDirection = s;
    }

    protected Exercise(Parcel in) {
        Name = in.readString();
        Time = in.readInt();
        SwitchDirection = in.readByte() != 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(Name);
        dest.writeInt(Time);
        dest.writeByte((byte) (SwitchDirection ? 1 : 0));
    }

    public static final Creator<Exercise> CREATOR = new Creator<Exercise>() {
        @Override
        public Exercise createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Exercise(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Exercise[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Exercise[size];
        }
    };
}
```

Activity 1:

```
     Exercise[] Exercises = new Exercise[]{
             new Exercise("Scisssors", 60, false),
             new Exercise("Cross Knee Planks", 60, false),
             new Exercise("Twisting Pistons", 30, false),
             new Exercise("Accordion Crunches", 60, true),
             new Exercise("Canoe Crunch", 30, false),
             new Exercise("Upper Circle Crunches", 30, true)
    };


    Intent i = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
    i.putExtra("Exercises", Exercises);
    startActivity(i);
```

Activity 2:

```
    Exercise[] Exercises;
    Exercises = (Exercise[]) getIntent().getParcelableArrayExtra("Exercises");
```

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with it from a quick glance, but seeing as you're trying to parcel an array, can the crash be an TransactionTooLargeException?

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't should send and get an array of Parcelable. You should give an array for Parcelable, and get it in Activity 2.
I have an example that send a HashMap between 2 activities.

```
public class BaseData implements Parcelable {

protected HashMap<String, Object> mData;

public BaseData(HashMap<String, Object> data) {
    mData = data;
}

protected BaseData(Parcel in) {
    try {
        mData = in.readHashMap(HashMap.class.getClassLoader());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static final Creator<BaseData> CREATOR = new Creator<BaseData>() {
    @Override
    public BaseData createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new BaseData(in);
    }

    @Override
    public BaseData[] newArray(int size) {
        return new BaseData[size];
    }
};

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    try {

        if (null == mData) {
            return;
        }

        dest.writeValue(mData);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}

public HashMap<String, Object> getData() {
    return mData;
}
```

}

In Activty 1 you will send data like that:

```
  HashMap<String, Object> hm = new HashMap<>();
    hm.put("data_1", array_data_1);
    hm.put("data_2",array_data_2);
    BaseData baseData = new BaseData(hm);
    BaseData baseData = new BaseData(data);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putParcelable("base_data", baseData);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context,Activity2.class)
    intent.putExtra("data",bundle);
```

In Activy 2 you will receive a bundle, then get basedata from bundle and get HashMap from basedata.

```
   Bundle bundle = getIntent().getBundleExtra("data");
    BaseData baseData = bundle.getParcelable("base_data");
    HashMap<String,Object> hm = baseData.getData();
```

You can replace HashMap by Array. If you can't implement it, please tell me I will send you a complete example.

Comment: Would you be able to include your code for receiving the hashmap on Activity2?